# Designing a self-upgrade strategy

Tags: windows, unix, coding-style

This is a general design/programming question.

I have been given the responsibility to design the upgrade strategy for our product. The product is run on remote devices with no user interaction. So we have to achieve everything remotely.

The product basically has two daemons/services running S1 and S2. While S2 does all the work and S1 oversees S2. S1 periodically checks S2 and restarts it if it is not running etc.

Now I need to write a self-upgrading capability into S1. S1 has to check with a server and if an upgrade is available it will have to download it (lets call it upgradeFile) and execute it.

Before executing the upgradeFile S1 will stop S2.

upgradeFile, when it executes, will attempt to replace the S1-disk-executable-file and S2-disk-executable-file with the new versions it is carrying.

After the execution of upgradeFile is finished, S1 will restart S2.

### Now I am very anxious of the fact that I am replacing the S1-disk-executable while S1 is running. With all the complexity of the loader and VM I am not sure if this is a good strategy.

I have checked the internet forums, books and I haven't found any articles talking about this. I don't even know if I am putting this question in the right forum.

I am currently programming on Linux Mint 14 and Qt 4.8. And we are also developing a new version for Android.

EDIT:
The product runs on remote dedicated hardware running Linux Mint. We do not have a Windows version. We are currently developing an Android version but I can deal with that later.

Comment: You might want to clarify what platform(s) the code to be upgraded will be running on, as well as what kind of application this is. Is this something running on a dedicated server, or is this a desktop application? The platform is relevant because *NIX OSes will generally allow you to write over running programs on disk, on Windows it's a bit tricky and the answer is generally that it won't allow it unless you set specific permissions which you might not have access to depending on how this is running.

Comment: @TomJacques The product runs on remote dedicated hardware running Linux Mint 14. We do not have a Windows version and its not a desktop application. We are currently developing an Android version but I can deal with that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix systems, there is no problem if you replace the executable file instead of overwriting it in place. A good strategy is:

- Prepare the new S1 executable in a temporary file in the same file-system as the original, say, `/usr/bin/S1.upgrade`.
- Rename `/usr/bin/S1.upgrade` to `/usr/bin/S1`. At this point, the current S1 process is still pointing at the old S1 i-node. Hence, no disk space has been freed yet and demand loading from the old executable is still possible, if a page-fault happens.
- Re-execute S1 (e.g., `execvp(argv[0], argv)`) such that the running process is upgraded to the new executable. The old i-node is now unreferenced and the old file actually deleted.

Most likely, no matter what is the distribution, the package manager will be doing some variation of this by default (minus restarting S1), so you might want to consider creating a package and simply using the default upgrade mechanism.

Comment: Thank you @jop. I did some tests and overwriting in place almost always works except when my code is making too many SQL queries. I will try your strategy above and check if that solves the problem.